# API calls reaches the limit

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

I am trying to make a website fetching data from an API. But the API call is limited to 100 calls per day. I am coding on a live server. So every time I make a change in my website the website automatically refreshed and the API calls. So while coding I lost my 100 calls of the day. Now my question is how can I avoid this call or is there any way I can stop the calls while coding?

Comment: If I was in your shoes,  I will try to capture the results of that api call, and put it in a function and call that function in place of the api during development,  you can easily replace your function with api call when you finished everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caching JavaScript API Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137597/caching-javascript-api-calls)

Comment: Cache the results of the call.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch the Data from API
2. Store it as a constant on your code where you make an API request and instead of making a call to API, simply use that constant as MOCKED response

If you always need updated data from API then better buy a plan from the API provider that gives unlimited access (if it is possible/feasible)